# CasperJS Screenshotting Different URLs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I've just started using CasperJS so I'm pretty stuck on an issue.

What I want to do is load a URL (Login protected), find a list of links (Which change the theme of the forum, specifically this part: ".styleChooser .overlayScroll li a"), click each of them and screenshot the result of the page after the click at two resolutions.

My code is currently just a grouping of other suggestions around the net trying to get this working, however I believe all the necessary code is basically there I just can't get it working. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

var screenshotUrl = "URL Here";
var screenshotPaths = "rivals";

function getLinks() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('.styleChooser .overlayScroll li a');
  links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
    return link.getAttribute('href');
  });
  return links;
}

screenshotNow = new Date(),
screenshotDateTime = screenshotNow.getFullYear() + pad(screenshotNow.getMonth() + 1) + pad(screenshotNow.getDate()),
viewports = [
{
  'name': 'smartphone-portrait',
  'viewport': {width: 320, height: 480}
},
{
  'name': 'desktop-standard',
  'viewport': {width: 1280, height: 1024}
}
];
i = -1;

casper.start();

casper.setHttpAuth('Username', 'Password');

casper.thenOpen(screenshotUrl, function(response) {
  var linksArray = this.evaluate(getLinks);
  this.eachThen(linksArray, function(response) {
    var url = response.data;
    this.each(viewports, function(casper, viewport) {
      this.then(function() {
        this.viewport(viewport.viewport.width, viewport.viewport.height);
      });
      this.thenOpen(url, function() {
        this.wait(5000);
      });
      casper.then(function(){
        casper.echo('Screenshot for '+ screenshotPaths + '/' + "homepage "  + viewport.name + ' (' + viewport.viewport.width + 'x' + viewport.viewport.height + ')', 'info');
        casper.capture('screenshots/' + screenshotPaths + '/' + screenshotDateTime + '/' + "homepage" + '/' + viewport.name + '-' + viewport.viewport.width + 'x' + viewport.viewport.height + '.png', {
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: viewport.viewport.width,
          height: viewport.viewport.height
        });
      });
    });
  });
  ++i;
}); // error is here
casper.run();

function pad(number) {
  var r = String(number);
  if ( r.length === 1 ) {
    r = '0' + r;
  }
  return r;
}
```

And this is the error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\caspertest>casperjs newestcasper.js
CasperError: You can only define a step as a function
  C:/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1755 in then
  C:/xampp/htdocs/caspertest/newestcasper.js:52
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with U
RL file:///C:/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match
.
```

Comment: I don't think this is it, but you should try to be consistent with the naming inside of the `this.each` callback. Either change the two `this` to casper or change the one `casper` into `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will certainly fix that up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the page that you want to take a screenshot of, you should use `thenOpen`. Right now, you use `then` which is only a step function without opening anything.

```
casper.thenOpen(screenshotUrl, function(response) {
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Artjom, that got rid of the error I was having. However now I'm getting no output, just simply runs. Is there any code I can add in there to give you a more specific output as to what's happening, an error log type of thing perhaps?

Comment: I don't see why this would be. Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but where should I run those events?

Comment: You register them anywhere you like, but you should do this before the `casper.start`.